# C# 'Enumerable.Repeat()' how to overload?

Tags: c#, linq, multidimensional-array, genetic-algorithm

I have written this code for a genetic algorithm that calculates jump hight by getting a random int for the genes (mass, height(of the speciment), and leg force) and then it reproduces itself with the other top-performing random specimens that are stored in a 2d array called `geneBoard`. Now to my problem; you see it's not practical to write out 1000 times the same values, so I tried to use this:

```
float[,] geneBoard = Enumerable.Repeat(
    mass = GetMass(500, 1000), 
    height = GetHeight(150, 190), 
    force = GetForce(500, 3500), 
    fitnessScore = Convert.ToSingle(PhysicalTest(mass, height, force)), 1000)
.ToArray();
```

instead of this:

```
float[,] geneBoard = new float[4, 4]
        {
            { mass = GetMass(500, 1000), height = GetHeight(150, 190), force = GetForce(500, 3500), fitnessScore = Convert.ToSingle(PhysicalTest(mass, height, force)) },
            { mass = GetMass(500, 1000), height = GetHeight(150, 190), force = GetForce(500, 3500), fitnessScore = Convert.ToSingle(PhysicalTest(mass, height, force)) },
            { mass = GetMass(500, 1000), height = GetHeight(150, 190), force = GetForce(500, 3500), fitnessScore = Convert.ToSingle(PhysicalTest(mass, height, force)) },
            { mass = GetMass(500, 1000), height = GetHeight(150, 190), force = GetForce(500, 3500), fitnessScore = Convert.ToSingle(PhysicalTest(mass, height, force)) }
        };
```

Here is all of my code if I didn't did a good enough job explaning:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Genetic_Algorithm
{
class Program
{
    static Random random = new Random(); // Getting a seed

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        float mass = GetMass(500, 1000);
        float height = GetHeight(150, 190);
        float force = GetForce(500, 3500);

        float fitnessScore = Convert.ToSingle( PhysicalTest(mass, height, force) );
        /*
        float[,] geneBoard = new float[4, 4]
        {
            { mass = GetMass(500, 1000), height = GetHeight(150, 190), force = GetForce(500, 3500), fitnessScore = Convert.ToSingle(PhysicalTest(mass, height, force)) },
            { mass = GetMass(500, 1000), height = GetHeight(150, 190), force = GetForce(500, 3500), fitnessScore = Convert.ToSingle(PhysicalTest(mass, height, force)) },
            { mass = GetMass(500, 1000), height = GetHeight(150, 190), force = GetForce(500, 3500), fitnessScore = Convert.ToSingle(PhysicalTest(mass, height, force)) },
            { mass = GetMass(500, 1000), height = GetHeight(150, 190), force = GetForce(500, 3500), fitnessScore = Convert.ToSingle(PhysicalTest(mass, height, force)) }
        };
        */
        float[,] geneBoard = Enumerable.Repeat(mass = GetMass(500, 1000), height = GetHeight(150, 190), force = GetForce(500, 3500), fitnessScore = Convert.ToSingle(PhysicalTest(mass, height, force)), 1000).ToArray();

        float[] sortingAr = new float[] { geneBoard[0, 3], geneBoard[1, 3], geneBoard[2, 3], geneBoard[3, 3] };
        Array.Sort(sortingAr, (x, y) => y.CompareTo(x));

        Console.WriteLine(sortingAr[0]);
        Console.WriteLine(sortingAr[1]);
    }

    public static float GetMass(int min, int max)
    {
        int massGr = random.Next(min, max);
        float mass = massGr / 10;

        return mass;
    }

    public static float GetHeight(int min, int max)
    {
        int heightCm = random.Next(min, max);
        float height = heightCm / 10;

        return height;
    }

    public static float GetForce(int min, int max)
    {
        int force = random.Next(min, max);

        return force;
    }

    public static double PhysicalTest(float mass, float height, float force)
    {
        double d = force * 0.07; // gets distance of applied force
        double vi = Math.Sqrt( (force * d) / ( mass / 2 ) ); // calculats v initial
        double jumpHeight = (vi * vi) / (2 * 9.8); // calculates jumping height

        double fitnessScore = jumpHeight * 100;

        return fitnessScore;
    }
}
```

}

Lastly, I am a beginner so any other suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: And what is your question/problem? You can´t overload a member if you don´t have access to its source-code, which I doubt you have for `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Enumerable.Repeat is a generic method that can return whatever you object you provide. There's no need to overload it.

Comment: "any other suggestions would be helpfull" don't use anonymous types. Make a class with all the variables that you use in the objects that are inside your array

Comment: Just use a for loop, it will not work (as you expect) with `Enumerable.Repeat`.

Comment: `Repeat` means *repeat* the sampe object over and over. What you typed though doesn't even compile. In fact, your `geneBoard` array declaration can't compile either - you want a *float* array which has no mass, height, force properties. It contains only floats

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos array declaration will compile, because `mass = GetMass(...)` is not property assignment, it's variable assignment, which returns value being assigned.

Comment: My problem is that it comes up with this error: No overload method 'Repeat' takes 5 arguments. Thanks a lot for responding.

Comment: You could probably do this with a array-of-array (`[4][]`) but @MongZhu 's suggestion is much better. mass, height score do not belong together in an array, that they are all `float` is coincidence.

Comment: @Evk no it won't. The code is trying to assign a collection of anonymous objects to a float array.

Comment: @SpyrosKasfikis `Repeat` *repeats* the same object as many times as you require. You didn't create an object, you tried some random syntax. The result is an `IEnumerable<TObject>` which can't be converted to a random type like `float[,]`. What are you trying to do? Why not create a specific class?

Comment: Do you know what a class is?  You should be using one of those instead of an array.  Enumerable.Repeat is for repeating the same instance, which is not what you want to do, so don't use repeat.  Find some other way.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos no it will :) You can try it yourself. Maybe not in all C# versions, not sure, but in latest it will.

Comment: @Evk I did and it won't. It's a 1-D array of *anonymous objects*, being assinge do a 2D array of *floats*.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos maybe we are talking about different code blocks. I mean one that is commented out in OPs sample code

Comment: @Evk there aren't many. Block 1 is `float[,] geneBoard = Enumerable.Repeat(mass = GetMass(500, 1000),` This won't compile. Block 2 is `float[,] geneBoard = new float[4, 4]{{ mass ` this won't compile

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos if they were anonymous objects then shouldn't the OP have used the `new` keyword at some point?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I guess you are trying to compile just this block, while you also need variable declarations above (`mass`, `height`, `force`, `fitnessScore`) for that to compile, because those variables are being assigned inside block, so you need to declare and initialize them.

Comment: What you probably want to use is actually a loop or something like this: `Enumerable.Range(1, 1000).Select(x => CreateNewThingHere())`

Comment: @Evk you are refering to the return value of the assignment which is an *accident* in the array's case, completely unexpected in `Repeat`.

Answer (score 6):

I think `Enumerable.Repeat` is not what you really want. As its name says, it simply repeats the *same* element over and over again, while in your case, I think what you want is to create 1000 *similar, yet different* objects that represent your genes.

In your case, I guess a simple `for` loop over an array you created previously would be absolutely suffcient.

Comment: Using for loop is best here indeed. Also there is no need to use classes, because any AI library will only accept arrays of floats for all computations.

Comment: Can you please present an example? Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: @SpyrosKasfikis do you mean an example of a `for` loop?

Comment: Yes, my main problem is I cannot figure out the syntax.

Comment: Never mind I figured it out. Thank you again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're having (No overload method 'Repeat' takes 5 arguments.) is normal because you're using Enumerable.Repeat the wrong way.

Enumerable.Repeat takes 2 arguments:

- The element to repeat
- How many times to repeat it

You're giving it 5 arguments, 4 of them describe AN element.

A workaround would be to create a class to hold your 4 values:

```
public class Element
{
    public float Mass { get; set; }
    public float Height { get; set; }
    public float Force { get; set; }
    public double FitnessScore { get; set; }

    // Add constructor to take the 4 parameters
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
Element[] elements = Enumerable.Repeat(new Element(GetMass(500, 1000), GetHeight(150, 190), GetForce(500, 3500), fitnessScore = Convert.ToSingle(PhysicalTest(mass, height, force)), 1000).ToArray();
```

You might wanna review your logic though. Because this will give you the SAME element 1000 times and I assume you want 1000 different objets with the same values.

Comment: This will give many referances to the same instance.  Either make `DataContainer` immutable or create separate instances.

Comment: I added a note for that.

Comment: If you assume that the OP wants different objects, why are you not showing an answer describing that? as already noted, this does not give the same result as requested